# How can I test that an item is removed from the page, with Capybara and Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write an integration test in Rails 3.0.8, using Capybara (head) and Selenium.  I'd like to test that when a user clicks the delete button for an item on my webpage, that the item actually gets deleted.   So On the webpage, I hide the item using the JQuery snippet

```
$('#interaction').fadeOut();
```

and I use the follow rspec test, and set the Capybara.default_wait_time to 5  sec, however nothing seems to give me a passing test.  How can I test this properly?

```
describe "A User adding an Interaction" do
  describe "when looking at an Item detail page" do
    it "should be able to delete and existing interaction", :js => true do
      sign_in_and_view_item
      page.should have_content "ITEM DETAILS - #{@item.name}"
      fill_in "interaction-input", :with  => "My Interaction"
      click_button "item-interaction-submit"
      page.should have_content "My Interaction"
      click_link "Delete Interaction"
      wait_until do
        page.evaluate_script('$.active') == 0
      end
      #page.should_not have_content "My Interaction"
      page.should have_no_content "My Interaction"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding this line to my spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

using this spec

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "A User adding an Interaction" do
  describe "when looking at an Item detail page" do
    it "should be able to delete and existing interaction", :js => true do
      sign_in_and_view_item
      page.should have_content "ITEM DETAILS - #{@item.name}"
      fill_in "interaction-input", :with  => "My Interaction"
      click_button "Save"
      page.should have_content "My Interaction"
      click_link "Delete Interaction"
      should_be_hidden "My Interaction"
    end
  end
end
```

along with this function should_be_hidden

```
def should_be_hidden text, selector=''
  sleep Capybara.default_wait_time
  its_hidden = page.evaluate_script("$('#{selector}:contains(#{text})').is(':hidden');")
  its_not_in_dom = page.evaluate_script("$('#{selector}:contains(#{text})').length == 0;")
  (its_hidden || its_not_in_dom).should be_true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara 2.1 supports the `has_text?` method which takes a type parameter `:visible`, which will check the page for all visible text.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text%3F-instance_method